# How can i do a double for loop and save it in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

Hi i'm trying to do a double for loop an save it in a dict. The code that i'm using is:

```
Results = 5, 10, 15, 20, 25
Multiples = ['Multiples1','Multiples2','Multiples3','Multiples4','Multiples5']

Example = {}
for Multiple in Multiples:
    for i in range(0,len(Results)):
        Example[Multiple] = Results[i]
```

I want that in "Example" each multiple go with the respective number like this:

```
{'Multiples1':5, 
'Multiples2':10, 
'Multiples3':15,
'Multiples4':20,
'Multiples5':25}
```

but the result that i get form this code is:

```
{'Multiples1': 25,
 'Multiples2': 25,
 'Multiples3': 25,
 'Multiples4': 25,
 'Multiples5': 25}
```

Comment: When you write `for Multiple in Multiples:` it traverses the `Multiples` array each element at a time. Now for each of these element you traverse from `0 to lengthOf(Results) -1 i.e. 04` and then assign it to your dictionary key.  So essentially, it takes each element of `Multiples` and keeps assigning it values from `Results` until it reaches the end. e.g `'Multiples1':5, 
'Multiples1':10, 
'Multiples1':15,
'Multiples1':20,
'Multiples1':25` This becomes your final result for each iteration.

Comment: Coming to the solution, Iterate over the `Multiples` array and assign element from `Results` array that are in the same position. ` for i in range(0,len(Multiples)):
        Example[Multiple[i]] = Results[i]` You can obviously tweak this code as per your requirements. Which brings me to the final part, Stack Overflow is not a place to get your homework solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a single `for` loop:

```
for i in range(len(Results)):
    Example[Multiples[i]] = Results[i]
```

---

Since your expected output is like this...

```
{
    'Multiples1':5, 
    'Multiples2':10,
    ...
}
```

...you can try a solution that doesn't involve the `Multiples` iterable:

```
for i in range(len(Results)):
    Example[f"Multiple{i}"] = Results[i]
```

---

You should be aware about how iterables are assigned in Python:

```
Results = 5, 10, 15, 20, 25 #This won't work
Results = [5, 10, 15, 20, 25] #This will work, and is a list
Results = {5, 10, 15, 20, 25} #This will work, and is a set
Results = (5, 10, 15, 20, 25) #This will work, and is a tuple
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a single for loop. In each iteration of your inner loop you overwrite the value of `Example[Multiple]`. So since the last value of `Results` is 25, all of your values end up as 25.
Try this:

```
for i in range(0, len(Results)):
    Example[Multiples[i]] = Results[i]
```

Comment: Notice that the `0` as first argument for `range` constructor is useless since it's the default value.